# Making Notepad++'s $ match the end of the file instead of the end of the line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I was wondering if there was a way of matching the end of a file in Notepad++ other than putting myself there a special combination of characters. By default, $ seems to match the end of the line, and not the end of a file.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try the following regex to match the end of your file:

```
\z
```

According to the [Notepad++ User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions)

```
\A or \` ⇒ Matches the start of the file.
\z or \' ⇒ Matches the end of the file.
```

For more info, the Notepad++ doc references the [Boost Regular Expression Syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), which is based on PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) syntax.